# Use crossref in bibliography, but only show the full main entry

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

Consider the following bibliography and MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography.bib}
@proceedings{conf:2006,
  editor    = {Star, Patrick and Tentacles, Squidward},
  title     = {Proceedings of the 1st Conference on Marine Biology},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the 1st Conference on Marine Biology},
  year      = 2006,
  month     = jan,
}

@inproceedings{proc:2006:01,
  title     = {How To Live Underwater},
  author    = {Squarepants, SpongeBob},
  pages     = {1--8},
  crossref  = {conf:2006}
}

@inproceedings{proc:2006:02,
  editor    = {Star, Patrick and Tentacles, Squidward},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the 1st Conference on Marine Biology},
  year      = 2006,
  month     = jan,
  title     = {How To Live Underwater},
  author    = {Squarepants, SpongeBob},
  pages     = {1--8},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

This results in the following bibliography:
[image: Output of MWE.]

My desired output would be to get item `[2]` (instead of `[1]` and `[3]`)  while citing `proc:2006:01` that uses a  `crossref` to `conf:2006`.

I would like to use the `crossref` field mainly as an easier way to manage my `.bib` file, and I am not particularly interested in showing an entry for the article and an entry for the conference in my references. I guess, in a sense, that would mean that the `conf:2006` entries are copied to `proc:2006:01` before it is processed. Is there a way I can do this? Preferably the solution would allow me to revert to the normal output if necessary.

I've tried the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123746/32206), but that only shows the fields of the main entry without inheriting the `crossref` entries. That's not what I want.

Comment: I am aware of the correct ordering, but I didn't think that it was an issue because all references were resolved. I guess `latexmk` did not show me the warnings. What you're saying is that the reason I was not getting the full bibliography entry when using `\cite{proc:2006:01}` is because the `crossref` entry was before the cited entry. Right? Also, depending on the number of times it is `crossref`ed, the `crossref` entry may appear separately in the references. I'll have to confirm tomorrow when I am using a PC. If that is the case, I was just being silly and I'll accept this as an answer.

Comment: @Mico: I guess the question, rather, is whether there is a way to avoid the ordering requirement. I sort my `.bib` entries by the key name and I'd rather avoid a silly naming scheme that will push them at the end of the `.bib` file.

Comment: @Mico Could you please convert your comment about the ordering into an answer so that I can accept it? I just tested it and it works fine. `latexmk` would not show me the warnings, so I thought that the ordering was not the issue. I'll also have to look for something more sophisticated than `bibsort` to sort my bibliography. Hopefully `bibtool` offers the "`crossref`-ed entries at the end" feature. If not, I guess I'll post another question. Thanks for the help! `:-)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Entries that are cross-referenced by other entries should occur later in the `.bib` file than any entries that cross-reference them. In practice, this means placing the entries that are cross-referenced *at the end* of the `.bib` file.

The fact that your MWE's `.bib` file has the entry being cross-referenced (key: `conf:2006`) coming first rather than last may be the cause of the problem behavior you're experiencing. If I rearrange your `.bib` file so that the entry with key `conf:2006` comes last, then executing either just `\cite{proc:2006:01}` (which cross-references `conf:2006`)  or `\cite{proc:2006:02}` (which does not) in the body of the document produces the identical entry in the bibliography.

Making sure that entries that are cross-referenced come *last* in the `.bib` file can be tedious, especially if the files contains lots and lots of entries and if you'd like to maintain some systematic sorting scheme. Fortunately, quite a few LaTeX-aware editors feature routines that simplify the task of pretty-printing bibliographic entries and sorting them according to various criteria. One particularly useful sorting criterion is to place all entries that are cross-referenced by other entries *last* in the file.