# Cross-referenced book reference has no title

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I have a number of items in my `.bib` file that all work as expected, including cross-referenced items. However, my latest addition (2 links to the same book) gives an "empty title" error and includes the book as a separate entry. What is different about the `liu2009` references?

I tried deleting one of the two refs to `liu2009` but got the same result. Similarly for a switch from `@inproceedings` to `@incollection`.
I am using TeXShop on a Mac, with `Natbib`. Here's a MWE:

`TeX` file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
Two references crossref'd to one book  \citep{gruber2009, stevens2009}, 
and one to another \citep{tangi1998}. \\
Error message ``BibTeX empty title in liu2009''.
\medskip
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References }
\bibliography{tempref}
\bibliographystyle{authordate1}
\end{document}
```

`Bib` file:

```
@incollection{tangi1998,
   author = {Tangi, Randee I},
   title = {Design and ...},
   chapter = {4},
   pages = {105-127},
   crossref = {fellbaum1998}
}
@inproceedings{gruber2009,
   author = {Gruber, Tom},
   title = {Ontology},
   pages = {1963-1965},
   crossref = {liu2009}
}
@inproceedings{stevens2009,
   author = {Stevens, Robert and Lord, Phillip},
   title = {Ontologies and Life Science...},
   pages = {1960-1963},
   crossref = {liu2009}
}
// -----------------------
@book{fellbaum1998,
   editor = {Fellbaum, Christiane},
   booktitle = {{WordNet}: an Electronic Lexical Database},
   publisher = {MIT Press},
   year = {1998}
}
@book{liu2009,
   editor = {Liu, Ling and {\"O}zsu, M Tamer},
   booktitle = {Encyclopedia of Database Systems},
   publisher = {Springer},
   year = {2009}
}
```

[image: Document produced]

Comment: Not sure about `natbib`, but with `biblatex` you would have `title` and not `booktitle` in a `@book`. So try `title = {Encyclopedia of Database Systems},`.

Comment: Thanks @moewe, that fixes the title in the "Liu" entry, but not in the cross-referenced items. Also, I'd rather the Liu entry doesn't appear separately, but only in combination with the others: like the Tangi/Fellbaum entry.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not a `natbib` expert.

Comment: I get a warning instead of an error, so I edited in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you use the wrong field for the `book` type, see the [BibTeX documentation](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/base), p.8

> **book** A book with an explicit publisher. Required fields: `author` or `editor`, `title`,
>   `publisher`, `year`. Optional fields: `volume` or `number`, `series`,
>   `address`, `edition`, `month`, `note`.

Further see on p.6 the part about the cross-referencing:

> 6. The standard styles use BibTEX’s new cross-referencing feature by giving
>      a `\cite` of the cross-referenced entry and by omitting from the cross-
>      referencing entry (most of the) information that appears in the cross-
>      referenced entry. These styles do this when a titled thing (the cross-
>      referencing entry) is part of a larger titled thing (the cross-referenced
>      entry). There are five such situations: when (1) an `INPROCEEDINGS` (or
>      `CONFERENCE`, which is the same) cross references a `PROCEEDINGS`; when
>      (2) a `BOOK`, (3) an `INBOOK`, or (4) an `INCOLLECTION` cross references a
>      `BOOK` (in these cases, the cross-referencing entry is a single volume in a
>      multi-volume work); and when (5) an `ARTICLE` cross references an `ARTICLE`
>      (in this case, the cross-referenced entry is really a journal, but there’s no
>      `JOURNAL` entry type; this will result in warning messages about an empty
>      author and title for the journal—you should just ignore these warnings).

For the cross-references of the two `inproceedings` you have to either change `@book{liu2009}` to `@proceedings{liu2009}` or change the two `inproceedings` to `inbook` or `incollection`.

There is an option for running BibTeX that was posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123746/28751), but I can't produced with that the desired output.

---

I am able to produce the desired output with `biblatex`/`biber`, which allows much more control over the appearance of bibliography entries.

You would need to change your main file to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    citestyle=authoryear,
    bibstyle=authoryear,
    natbib=true,
    mincrossrefs=3,
  ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{tempref.bib}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
Two references crossref'd to one book  \citep{gruber2009, stevens2009}, 
and one to another \citep{tangi1998}. \\
Error message ``BibTeX empty title in liu2009''.
\medskip
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References }
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Put the number in `mincrossrefs=3,` to the value from which on you want to have the main entry appear. I made it here 3 which is the lowest one for which your example works. By setting it to 2, the entry for `liu2009` appears while `fellbaum1998` is not included.

Comment: That fixed the problem (after I changed the liu2009 from 'booktitle' to 'title'). However, the Liu book still appears in the reference list. I also need to use natbib on the main, larger project: I'll keep working on the problem.

Comment: @eknumbat I have now the Liu book dissapearing by using `biblatex`/`biber`. Also note that there is a `natbib` compatibility option that allows to use the `\citep` commands and so on. I added also a link to a related question concerning `bibtex`, but it does not work for me.

Comment: Adding mincrossrefs=3 fixed the extra unwanted ref, and the natbib option is likely to come in useful too. Thanks @jjdb!

Comment: @eknumbat I just mention it once more: set the number higher than 3 (10 or higher) if you don't want the Liu book to suddenly show up if you have a third cross-ref linking to it.